# jQuery UI - How to trigger sortupdate event properly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery v1.8.0 and jQuery UI v1.8.22.

The documentation said that you can trigger sortupdate by:

```
 $(".selector").bind("sortupdate", function (event, ui) {
     // do something here
 });

 $(".selector").trigger("sortupdate");
```

But this doesn't seem to be the case because `ui` is undefined. Is there any other way to make this work / trigger events on sortupdate?

Comment: Without investigating very deeply, it seems to me that if `ui` is undefined, that's a problem. Are the resources being included in the right order (jQuery, jQuery UI), does the jQuery UI package contain sortable, and is the binding attempted after the document is scriptable? (for example, within the document ready function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sortupdate` is triggered once sorting has stopped and the DOM has changed. It should happen automatically and is not intended to be 'triggered' in any other way. That's not to say you can't trigger the event, however, if you don't pass it 'ui', then it'll be undefined.

When the sortable triggers the event, ui will not be undefined.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to pass it `ui`?

Comment: There may be a way using some undocumented internal functions of jQuery UI, but I would advise against it. The ui variable contains information about the item being dragged which will be hard to simulate when calling the event externally.