# CKEditor no longer editable after dragging

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a page that includes multiple ckeditors:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l4vB.png

The wrappers of the editors are draggable. If I drag one of the editors to another position and drop it, it's no longer editable and the content disappears:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvSzs.png

I though I could solve this by destroying that specific editor and then re-initialising it, but when I do that, I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'clearCustomData' of null ckeditor.js:635

Has anyone ever encountered this issue?

This is the javascript I'm using:

```
function initSortable() {
    $('.sortable').sortable({
        handle  : '.sortable-handle'
    }).bind('sortupdate', function(e) {
        updateBlockOrder();
        // Get the dropped content block
        var _el = $(e.delegateTarget).children('.dropped');
        if (_el.find('.rte').length) {
            // Get id of each area and re-initialize
            _el.find('.rte').each(function(){
                var _id = $(this).attr('id');
                console.log(_id);
                var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[_id];
                console.log(editor);
                editor.destroy();
            });
        }
    });

}
```

The output is as follows:

```
form-blocks-2-body app.js:540

b {element: CKEDITOR.dom.element, elementMode: 1, name: "form-blocks-2-body", _: Object, commands: Object…}
_: Object
blockless: false
commands: Object
config: b
container: CKEDITOR.dom.element
dataProcessor: CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor
element: CKEDITOR.dom.element
elementMode: 1
filter: CKEDITOR.filter
focusManager: CKEDITOR.focusManager
getClipboardData: function (b,c){function e(a){a.removeListener();a.cancel();c(a.data)}
id: "cke_3"
instanceReady: true
keystrokeHandler: CKEDITOR.keystrokeHandler
lang: b
langCode: "en"
loaded: true
mode: "wysiwyg"
name: "form-blocks-2-body"
plugins: Object
readOnly: false
resetUndo: function (){b.reset();a.fire("saveSnapshot")}
status: "ready"
tabIndex: 0
templates: Object
toolbar: Array[13]
toolbox: t
ui: CKEDITOR.ui
__proto__: Object
 app.js:542

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'clearCustomData' of null
```

Comment: Destroying and reinitialising should work if you do that correctly (in the right moments). I'm afraid that you need to create a sample to show us how you implemented this. Without this I can only guess that you try to destroy wrong instance on you do this too late.

Comment: I've updated the post so it includes the javascript I'm using

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895186/jquery-ui-how-to-trigger-sortupdate-event-properly - `sortupdate` is fired to late. You need to destroy editor before it was detached.